# CKEditor image width and height as HTML attribute in stead of inline styling

Tags: javascript, html, image, plugins, ckeditor

I´m making an email program website which allows you to upload images. You can resize the image but it will be written as inline styling: `style="width: X; heigth: X"`.

When you want to preview your email inside outlook the image will be shown with full width and height.

So instead of

```
<img src="x" style="width: x; heigth: x";>
```

I want

```
<img src="x" width="x" heigth="x">
```

I'm currently using the latest version of CKEditor: V4.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_acf-section-example%3A-disallow-inline-styles-and-use-attributes-instead. This link describes exactly what you are looking for.

Please note that for this to work Advanced Content Filter (ACF) needs to be enabled. If you are not familiar with it, please see:

- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addTransformations
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent

Comment: Thank you mate. I've found an plugin: "Enhanced Image" that does it automaticcly for me. Also they give the possibility to resize the image!

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I actually had that in mind and forgotten to suggest that :)